# How to do multithreading with Shoes? Shoes.app blocks

Tags: ruby, shoes, shoes-4

After quite some headache, I realized that the `Shoes.app` call blocks the execution of further code. I tried wrapping it in `Thread.new` but then the window doesn't get displayed. How can I launch a window and manipulate it from the outside?

```
require 'shoes'

app = Shoes.app do
  para "I block the execution."
  button "I've seen enough" do
     exit
  end
end

print("Called when the window terminates")
```

I originally thought the problem was me incorrectly saving and handling `app` or it's variables inside the block, since there is a special line about it in the manual (http://shoesrb.com/manual/Rules.html on Block Redirection) and what I did outside of the block didn't change the window. In my opinion, the manual is not very clear on blocking.

Comment: Just them through the eyelets and make a bow... _har har har_

Comment: ...Why not wrap your other code in a thread? Generally, the GUI thread is the main one, anyway, because you normally want everything else to stop when the GUI is closed (_closed_, not _hidden_). Otherwise, your users are going to be surprised that your app is still running in the background when they could have sworn they closed it.